# In IE, removing items from an Ext.form.FieldSet causes the FieldSet to expand

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, extjs

I have an ExtJS project in which I have a FieldSet that I need to dynamically remove items from and replace with different items.

When I remove items and then add new items, however, the FieldSet expands slightly each time, so that the entire FieldSet grows and grows and grows.

This only happens in IE - not Firefox or Chrome.

Here is my Fieldset...

```
var lonFields = new Ext.form.FieldSet({
        ref: '../../setLonFieldSet',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 2
        }
});
```

Here is where I reference it, remove everything, and then add new stuff...

```
Ext.getCmp('maintainGeneratorsBatteriesViewport').setLonFieldSet.removeAll();
Ext.getCmp('maintainGeneratorsBatteriesViewport').setLonFieldSet.add(
                {html: "<b>Default Lon:</b>"}   
            );
Ext.getCmp('maintainGeneratorsBatteriesViewport').setLonFieldSet.add(
                {html: "<b>Default Lon:</b>"}   
            );
```

As I said, in IE this causes the entire FieldSet to grow in height each time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: This is definitely a bug that you should report in the sencha forum. Please provide the ie version in which it occurs.

Comment: Yepper.  It definitely seems to be a bug.  No matter how simple you make it - it always adds and extra line of pixels.  About the only thing to do at this point is simply not to use a table layout if you want to remove and then add rows.  If you use another type of layout, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var fieldSet = Ext.getCmp('your fieldset id');
fieldSet.removeAll(fieldSet.items);
fieldSet.doLayout();
```

After doing this you can add new item !! :)